# list() gives TypeError: 'Node' object is not callable - BUT ONLY AFTER SOME CODES

Tags: python, nuke

I hope this is an easy one for you guys.

This is my script, for Nuke.

```
selNodes = nuke.selectedNodes()

for list in selNodes:
    if list.Class() == 'Read':
        layerArray = []
        # Get the list of layers and make unique using set
        for chanList in list.channels():
            channelLayer = chanList.split('.')
            layerArray.append(channelLayer[0])

        print list(set(layerArray))
```

It gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: 'Node' object is not callable
```

So I tried a simpler code of the same nature:

```
a = [1, 1]
print list(set(a))
```

And it didn't work. Same error message. Now here's the strange thing: I opened up a new Nuke and ran the simpler codes again, it worked. I couldn't understand why, but I was happy. So I put in my original codes and ran it, error message. I deleted them, the editor is now clean. And ran the simpler code again, error message!!

Which means that a working code can be rendered failure after I pasted and deleted something else!

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? Nuke is a very established software I don't know if it's a software bug.

Comment: It's because you've redefined `list` in the `for list in selNodes:` loop. Change it to `for lst in selNodes:`.

Answer (score 2):

It is because, you are using `list` as the loop variable, which hides the builtin function [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list). You are using that function in

```
print list(set(layerArray))
```

The loop variables are leaked even when the loop is over, check this program to understand better

```
for i in range(10):
    pass
print(i)
```

This will print `9`. It means that, `i` is still available in the program even after the loop is over. The case in your program, after iterating over the `selNodes`, `list` variable has the last variable. And you are trying to call that like a function when you say

```
print list(set(layerArray))
```

That's why it fails. There are two ways to fix this.

1. Just change the loop variable to something else.
2. <strike>Use `del list` when the loop is over.</strike> Just pretend that I didn't suggest this. This is **NOT** recommended. Just change the loop variable to something else.